# leaflet-providers for products, "Not a valid origin for the client: "

Tags: leaflet

I tried to use the layers of this [website](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/). When I developed it locally, there was no problem. After I deployed the page online, my layers needed some kind of authorization, and my website was not allowed to be accessed.

Error messagee:

```
"Not a valid origin for the client: https://this-is-my-web-url has not been registered for client ID **********.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
```

This [document](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) does not mention how to do authentication, only that the following method can be used to enter the layer:

```
// add Stamen Watercolor to map.
L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor').addTo(map);
```

`Stamen.Watercolor` is the name of the layer.

The `Stamen.Watercolor` layer in the sample file can run successfully, but the `Stadia.AlidadeSmoothDark` layer I chose cannot be read successfully.

```
L.tileLayer.provider('Stadia.AlidadeSmoothDark').addTo(map);
```

[Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/t5iDDpoox3JutqRw?preview)

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/5TTrO0gmsHqnI8SH). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @IvanSanchez Sorry I modified my question, I used the layer Stadia.AlidadeSmoothDark

Comment: Read https://docs.stadiamaps.com/raster/ , specifically «and everything should work seamlessly *as long as you have an active plan for your domain*».